# How do I kill all outbound wireless/RF (Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, etc.) traffic on startup?

Tags: networking, wifi, startup, bluetooth

I would like something with the effect of

```bash
rfkill block all
```

to run when my machines boots.

XFCE allows me to run the command "on login", but I am concerned this allows RF transmission before I log in with my credentials.

How do I prevent all RF transmission until I explicitly enable Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or other wireless features?

Relevant System Details:

```
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
Kernel: 5.19.17-2-MANJARO 
DE: Xfce 4.18 
WM: Xfwm4
```

Comment: Google: how to create a systemd unit

Comment: You can likely modify your grub config to add `module_blacklist=<module_name>` to the boot line. Substitute in your specific modules. You can then manually add in the modules (as root) when you want to enable wireless.

Comment: module blacklist will make it impossible to reenable the device without rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Artem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov) suggested, creating a systemd unit that executes `rfkill block all` is one solution.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html